# Class for modifying stats of units

Tags: java, game, enum, battle-simulation

I am specifically looking for input on naming `ModifierCalculator` and `Modifiers`. I would also appreciate input on whether `ModifierCalculator` should extend `EnumMap` instead of having it as a field.

These classes are for modifying the status of units. The `StatType` enum contains different types of ..stats, such as "life", "armor", "weapon damage", etc.

`StatModifier` objects' purpose is to modify a unit's stat. This kind of modification can be a flat bonus, a percentage increment or a multiplication, using the formula

```
total = (base + flat)*(1 + percent_increments)*(1 + mult_1)*(1 + mult_2)*... *(1 + mult_n)
```

`ModifierCalculator` puts all three kinds of modifiers in a map of `Modifiers` data structures with `StatType` serving as keyword.

```
public enum StatType
{
    //code is trivial to the problem
}

public enum StatModifierType
{
    FLAT, PERCENTAGE, MULTIPLICATIVE;
}

public class StatModifier
{
    private StatType statType;
    private double magnitude;
    private StatModifierType modType;

    public StatModifier(StatType statType, double magnitude, StatModifierType modType)
    {
        this.statType = statType;
        this.magnitude = magnitude;
        this.modType = modType;
    }

    public StatType getStatType()
    {
        return statType;
    }

    public double getMagnitude()
    {
        return magnitude;
    }

    public StatModifierType getModifierType()
    {
        return modType;
    }
}

public class Modifiers
{
    public double flat = 0;
    public double percentage = 0;
    public final ArrayList<Double> multipliers = new ArrayList<Double>();
}

public class ModifierCalculator
{
    private EnumMap<Stat, Modifiers> statToModifiers
          = new EnumMap<Stat, Modifiers>(Stat.class);

    public ModifierCalculator()
    {
        for (StatType s : Stat.values())
            statToModifiers.put(s, new Modifiers());
    }

    public void evaluate(ArrayList<StatModifier> modifiers)
    {
        for (StatModifier modifier : modifiers)
            evaluate(modifier);
    }

    public void evaluate(StatModifier modifier)
    {
        double magnitude = modifier.getMagnitude();
        Modifiers mods = statToModifiers.get(modifier.getStat());
        switch (modifier.getModifierType())
        {
        case FLAT:
            mods.flat += magnitude;
            break;
        case PERCENTAGE:
            mods.percentage += magnitude;
            break;
        case MULTIPLICATIVE:
            mods.multipliers.add(1 + magnitude);
            break;
        }
    }

    public Modifiers getStatModifiers(StatType statType)
    {
        return statToModifiers.get(statType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any real need to distinguish between multiplicative and percentual modifiers? They seem to serve the same purpose with just different ranges, so you maybe can merge them together?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "just different ranges." They don't serve the same purpose.

Comment: In your description you state that "(base + flat)*(1 + percent_increments)*(1 + mult_1)*(1 + mult_2)*... *(1 + mult_n)" . How is this different from " (base + flat)*(1 + mult_0)*(1 + mult_1)*(1 + mult_2)*... *(1 + mult_n)" ? Their behavior is the same, it seems to me that it only changes the range (percentage is 0-1, multipliers are > 1), but I may be wrong.

Comment: Multipliers range: (-1, infinite)

Percent range: (0, infinite)


% modifiers increase the value of flat modifiers.

Multipliers increase the value of flat modifiers, % modifiers and other multipliers.

How do make new lines

Comment: Even if their range is different, you are still applying them as multiplication to the base+flat value, which is the same you do for the percentage, right? So I don't see the point for splitting them (unless there are reasons external to the snippets provided)

Comment: Example: you have a 50% increase and another 50% increase, total increase is 100%.
Example 2: you have a 150% multipler and another 150% multipler, total is 125% increase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO The names are fine. You could maybe want to modify `Modifiers` in `StatModifiersSummary` as it's, after all, a summary "view" of the actual modifiers.

You should make its fields final or private, though.

In that case, your calculator would become `StatModifiersSummaryCalculator`.

W.r.t. extending / having one map inside, composition is in general preferable to inheritance, so stick with the current design: after all you happen to use a Map, but there is no reason why you couldn't use another representation and you don't want your "users" to be able to pass your calculator around where a map is needed.

Comment: Making its fields final wouldn't make any sense. As for making them private, I just don't see the point.

Comment: @Aeailmuawe Both the options are suggested for guaranteeing encapsulation: it's a public reachable class, someone may otherwise accidentally overwriting your values AFTER you evaluate them by doing getStatModifier(xxx).percentage = 100000. Granted, if you are the only user of the code, no problem, but then this argument would hold in the same way for every instance of the "encapsulation" problem

Comment: Making them final would actually break it. As for "encapsulation", if I add setters and getters then anything that can call `getStatModifier` will still be able to call the setters. Following this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-137265.html#177 10.1

Comment: @Aeailmuawe Making it final (or removing the setters), would need you to refactor your code to work with immutable "Modifiers" class. This would require to change your logic to use copy-like constructors (and guaranteeing that the users accessing it don't store the old modifiers object). I am not familiar with your project, so it may be an overkill, especially if you are sure that no one ever will access the fields for writing except the calculator, but I'd argue that, in general, beans should be immutable unless needed otherwise. it's just good practice (imho)

Comment: I prefer using private fields in objects and public ones in data structures.

Comment: That's fine. I'd just recommend making them final then to avoid accidental editing by users. But it's not the end of the world.